# Processing mouse wheel events in Qt4.8

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt-quick, qt4.8

In Qt5 it can be done in QML like this.

```
MouseArea {
    onWheel: {
        if (wheel.modifiers & Qt.ControlModifier) {
            adjustZoom(wheel.angleDelta.y / 120);
        }
    }
}
```

How to achieve the same in Qt4.8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I'm reinventing the bicycle but here is how it works for now.

I have a new QWidget that catches the wheelEvent and sends a new signal.

```
void WheelEventCarrier::wheelEvent(QWheelEvent *event)
{
    emit sendWheelEvent(event->delta()/120);
}
```

I define a new signal in QML and process it ibid.

```
signal wheelEvent(int delta)

onWheelEvent:
{
    if(delta > 0)
        tag_meas_mod.zoomIn(true);
    else
        tag_meas_mod.zoomOut(true);
}
```

I wrap my widget around all my UI and connect the two signals.

```
WheelEventCarrier carrier;
UI.setParent(&carrier);

QObject::connect(&carrier,
                     SIGNAL(sendWheelEvent(int)),
                     viewer.rootObject(),
                     SIGNAL(wheelEvent(int)));

carrier.show();
```

Hope you can point me to a better solution.

Comment: Or I can create a new QDeclarative item and catch events with 'wheelEvent(QGraphicsSceneWheelEvent *event)'